# magento2.4.6 Unable to save operations related to category

Tags: magento2.4.6

I am using **magento2.4.6** and when I click save after making any changes in **admin>catalog>categories** it will prompt an error:

**Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath():Argument #1 ($path) must be of type string, array given, called in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 172
Exception in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php:213**

I can't change name or content and picture if you know how to fix please help me thanks

Comment: Check this answare I believe it fits https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174357/magento-issues-when-saving-categories

Answer (score 0):

Try these , I think any of this will work for you

- Clear the Magento cache: Run php bin/magento cache:clean from the
  root directory.
- Upgrade dependencies: Execute composer update to ensure dependencies
  are up to date.
- Review customizations or extensions: Check for any modifications or
  overrides related to category management.
- Undo recent changes: Revert any recent updates or installations that
  might be causing conflicts.
- Check Magento version compatibility: Ensure your Magento version
  (2.4.6) is compatible with installed extensions.